# What's `InherentDataProviders`? How can I use them?

Tags: inherent

I've seen some code like this

```rust
move |_, ()| async move {
    let uncles =
        sp_authorship::InherentDataProvider::<<Block as BlockT>::Header>::check_inherents();
    let timestamp = sp_timestamp::InherentDataProvider::from_system_time();
    let slot =
        sp_consensus_babe::inherents::InherentDataProvider::from_timestamp_and_duration(
            *timestamp,
            slot_duration,
        );

    Ok((timestamp, slot, uncles))
},
```

But I don't know what it means. If I remove one of them, the node still can be compiled and running without any issue.

Or I should ask what is `InherentData`. What does it use for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InherentDataProvider` is a type that provides data to inherents.

> Each inherent is added to a produced block. Each runtime decides on which inherents it wants to attach to its blocks. All data that is required for the runtime to create the inherents is stored in the `InherentData`. This `InherentData` is constructed by the node and given to the runtime.

- [Source](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/be8bb186d87b9d2b47a2907c9b51ae1e252362c3/primitives/inherents/README.md#L3)

As to the specific code that you are referencing, maybe these two PR's can help:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/8029
- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/4973/files